# Convert shapefile to integer array file

Tags: raster, shapefile, integer

I have a shapefile similar to the one below. This shapefile shows zones in a specific model. The model cell size is 100 x 100 m.

[image]

I want to convert it to integer array file with unique integer value assigned for each zone.
For example, the .dat file below

[image]

Any suggestion how can I do that? in R, Python or QGIS?

Comment: You could convert your polygon to raster as type AAIGRID https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_conversion/rasterize.html then remove the first few rows that contain the cell size, nodata and origin information. If it's a huge raster a quick python script to open the ASCII file, read and discard the first few lines then open and write the input to an output dat file would do the trick and run surprisingly fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rasterize:
[image]
Convert to numpy array and [savetxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

rlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Rasterized")[0]

ds = gdal.Open(rlayer.source())
myarray = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()).astype(int)
np.savetxt("/home/bera/Desktop/out.dat",myarray,'%i')
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. You made my day! Exactly what I wanted. Many thanks :)